# Why Exception Handling doesn't print text?

Tags: python-3.x

My question is why Python doesn't execute the print statement in the Exception Handling code below. I am trying to calculate the log of volumes for a bunch of stocks. Each stock has 1259 volume values. But Python generates a RunTimeWarning "divide by zero encountered in log". So I try to use Exception Handling to locate where the log input is zero, but Python doesn't execute the print statement under except. The print statement is supposed to print the name of the stock and the index in the array where the volume is zero. Why?

Here is the code:

```
for i, stock in enumerate(df.columns):
    volumes = df[stock].to_numpy()
    for r in range(len(volumes)):   # len(volumes) = 1259
        try:
            v = np.log(volumes[r])
        except:
            print(stock, r)
```

Here is the Error that follows after the RunTimeWarning.

```
LinAlgError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-6aa283671e2c> in <module>
     13         closes = df_close[stock].to_numpy()
     14         volumes = df_vol[stock].to_numpy()
---> 15         indicator_values_all_stocks[i] = indicator.price_volume_fit(volumes, closes, histLength)
     16 
     17     indicator_values_all_stocks_no_NaN =  indicator_values_all_stocks[:, ~np.isnan(indicator_values_all_stocks).any(axis=0)]

~\Desktop\Python Projects Organized\Finance\Indicator Statistics\B.57. Price Volume Fit\indicator.py in price_volume_fit(volumes, closes, histLength)
   1259         x = log_volumes[i - histLength:i]
   1260         y = log_prices[i - histLength:i]
-> 1261         model = np.polyfit(x, y, 1, full = True)
   1262         slope[i] = model[0][0]
   1263 

<__array_function__ internals> in polyfit(*args, **kwargs)

c:\users\donald seger\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py in polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond, full, w, cov)
    629     scale = NX.sqrt((lhs*lhs).sum(axis=0))
    630     lhs /= scale
--> 631     c, resids, rank, s = lstsq(lhs, rhs, rcond)
    632     c = (c.T/scale).T  # broadcast scale coefficients
    633 

<__array_function__ internals> in lstsq(*args, **kwargs)

c:\users\donald seger\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in lstsq(a, b, rcond)
   2257         # lapack can't handle n_rhs = 0 - so allocate the array one larger in that axis
   2258         b = zeros(b.shape[:-2] + (m, n_rhs + 1), dtype=b.dtype)
-> 2259     x, resids, rank, s = gufunc(a, b, rcond, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
   2260     if m == 0:
   2261         x[...] = 0

c:\users\donald seger\miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag)
    107 
    108 def _raise_linalgerror_lstsq(err, flag):
--> 109     raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")
    110 
    111 def get_linalg_error_extobj(callback):

LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares
```

Comment: Because a RuntimeWarning is not an exception, it's a warning.

Comment: But the program stops and generates an error after the RunTimeWarning.

Comment: What's the error? You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69700018/edit) including the error and its full traceback.

Comment: Updated the question with the Error Message. Thank u for pointing that out. I just focused on the RunTimeWarning that comes right before the Error Message.

Comment: By the error message it seems that the exception has not been raised by the line in the try clause. It has been raised by the call to `fit`, and the error is due to the model not converging.

Comment: When the model does not converge, it is in my experience usually because of the existence of NaN values, which in turn is caused by division by zero, or log(zero). That is why I believe the RunTimeWarning issue may be the cause of the Error.

Comment: @Alex you may be right, however you will not be able to catch the exception with a try/except block that does not contain the line raising the exception. You can replace the try/except block with an if statement checking for potential arithmetic issues.